# How to recreate this image warping effect?

Tags: image-processing

I'm looking to create image warping effect that looks like this animation, which resembles a misshapen magnifying glass being moved over a background:

[image]

Not sure where to start, but here are some related posts:

- [Correcting image distortion by warping a set of distorted points to a corresponding set of undistorted points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75896/correcting-image-distortion-by-warping-a-set-of-distorted-points-to-a-correspond)
- [Captcha text morphing effect](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191411/captcha-text-morphing-effect)

Comment: Maybe also related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/234660/72682. The hard part is working out what `ImageTransformation` you need to apply.

Comment: Another with distortion: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15065/363

Comment: This is solely [`ImageTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTransformation.html). The transformation is a simplified form of [blackhole effect](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/interstellar-image-effects) with two or three moving blackholes. It is hard to reconstruct the trajectories exact.

Comment: Try machine learning. Train a neural net with many such images and then ask your question (easier said than done).

Comment: If you have access to the tool that generated this effect, then it may be possible to track randomly coloured pixels via frame-to-frame optical flow. I'd start off with: `ImageResize[RandomImage[1, {32, 32}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"], {200, 200},
  Resampling -> "Nearest"]`. The up-sampling is to mitigate colour shifts when the filter resamples after distortion. It would be very difficult but it's probably the best way to reproduce this exact distortion.

Answer (score 12):

We can use cylindrical functions with `ImageTransformation[]` to show waves on the water, for example

```
img=
```

[image: Figure 0]

```
lst = Table[
   ImageTransformation[
    img, {#[[
        1]] (1 + 
         Sin[Pi x/40] BesselJ[1, 
           20 Sin[Pi x/
               40] Sqrt[(#[[1]] - .5)^2 + (#[[2]] - .5)^2]]), #[[
        2]] (1 + 
         Sin[Pi x/40] BesselJ[1, 
           15 Sin[Pi x/
               40] Sqrt[(#[[1]] - .5)^2 + (#[[2]] - .5)^2]])} &,  
    Padding -> "Periodic"], {x, 0, 40, 1/2}];
```

[image: Figure 1]

And with some azimuthal waves

```
lst = Table[
   ImageTransformation[
    img, {#[[
         1]] (1 + 
          Sin[Pi x/40] Cos[4 Pi ArcTan[#[[1]], 1 - #[[2]]]] BesselJ[1,
             20 Sin[
              Pi x/40] Sqrt[(#[[1]] - .5)^2 + (1 - #[[2]])^2]]), #[[
         2]] (1 + 
          Sin[Pi x/40] Sin[4 Pi ArcTan[#[[1]], 1 - #[[2]]]] BesselJ[1,
             20 Sin[
              Pi x/40] Sqrt[(#[[1]] - .5)^2 + (1 - #[[2]])^2]])} (1 + 
        x/20 Sin[Pi x/40]) &, Padding -> "Periodic"], {x, 0, 40, 
    1/2}];
```

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 8):

Here is the beginning of the transformation in slow motion. We see that the top right and bottom left quadrants are getting heavily distorted in a symetrical way, while the other two quadrants are tilting.

(The gif below was obtained by saving the original gif, then use `Import` to import the file as a list of 181 images, then `Export` the first 40 or so of these images as a new gif with the option `DiplayDurations->0.6`).

[image]

Does this help figure out how to do it? It is likely a clue, but I don't know what it means.

The following transformation shows some potential.

```
list = Table[
  ImageTransformation[img, Sin[x Pi #] Sin[ Pi Reverse[#]] &], {x, 
   0.3, 0.70, 0.01}]
```

Here is the list as a gif.

[image]

Of course there are endless possible variations:

```
list = Table[
  ImageTransformation[img, 
   0.70 # + 0.1  Sin[x Pi #] Sin[Pi Reverse[#]] + 0.1 &], {x, 0.3, 
   2.70, 0.01}]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add some code to your answer?

Comment: This is really a question, not an answer. Does the fact that we have quadrants affected differently provide a clue as to the kind of function used in the transformation? The second image is just an example of a failed, but entertaining attempt. I did not keep the code.

Comment: Maybe do background subtraction first? Also please post code for this we can ping pong ideas in that way...